# Stepping over AOP method interceptors in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, aop

I am using AOP framework SNAP to intercept my methods.
Every time i am in debug and stepping through code it enters the interceptor.
How can I surpass (ignore) this interceptor so when I do F11 (step into) my method, I go straight to my method not first the interceptor.

Is there a visual studio setting to allow bypassing some methods when debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried decorating your interceptor class or method with the [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx)?